# Trigger popup on link click

Tags: html

How can I trigger a popup on link/button click? I'm using the Sumome page builder and I would like to trigger it on link click. I saw it used on other websites like this: `<button data-sumome-listbuilder-id="idnumber">Join</button>`
But for some reason, when I insert my Sumome idnumber, it doesn't work (nothing pops up, it just displays a button that does nothing)

Comment: How did you solve this problem? If you found a solution please post the answer for others to find!

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe your button stop of working when you changed it's id because there was an event-listener attached on the previous id (when you change it you must update the event-listener script aswell). It's hard to be sure without a piece of code to check. Anyway, if you want to build a new pop-up instead of editing the current ones:*

Pop-ups are blocked on browsers by default and take some seconds to load. The best option is use a modal div with `position:fixed` instead and hide/show it using `display:none` / `display:inline-block`

```js
function show(){
  document.getElementById("zero").style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById("aa").style.display = "inline-block";  
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById("zero").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("aa").style.display = "none";   
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: honeydew;
}

#zero {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;;
}

#aa {  
  font-weight: bold;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;  
  background: #fff;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

a, a:visited, a:focus {
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: crimson; 
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  background: darkred;  
}

#text {
  text-align: justify;
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}

.left {
  float: left;  
}

.right {
  float: right;  
}
```

```html
<div id=zero style="display:none"></div>
<div id=text><a href=# target=_self onClick="show()" class=left>click to open</a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam nibh. Nunc varius facilisis eros. Sed erat. In in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet. Curabitur adipiscing luctus massa. Integer ut purus ac augue commodo commodo. Nunc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer. Etiam vitae nisl. In dignissim lacus ut ante. Cras elit lectus, bibendum a, adipiscing vitae, commodo et, dui. Ut tincidunt tortor. Donec nonummy, enim in lacinia pulvinar, velit tellus scelerisque augue, ac posuere libero urna eget neque. Cras ipsum. Vestibulum pretium, lectus nec venenatis volutpat, purus lectus ultrices risus, a condimentum risus mi et quam. Pellentesque auctor fringilla neque. Duis eu massa ut lorem iaculis vestibulum. Maecenas facilisis elit sed justo. Quisque volutpat malesuada velit.</div>

<div id=aa style="display:none">
<a href=# target_self onClick="hide()" class=right>x</a>
<p>content A</p><p>content B</p><p>content C</p><p>content D</p>
</div>
```

**Anyway**, if you want a real pop-up window, you can do it like this:

HTML

```
<a href=# target=_self onClick="pop()">click to open</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function pop() { window.open('http://www.example.com','pop',"height=590,width=450,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=auto,resizable=yes,copyhistory=no"); }
```

[**codepen DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZPQNZ)

*As you see on the Javascript line, there's several attributes like 'width' and 'height' to customize your pop-up window.*

Answer (score 0):

you can try javascript. Or for fast checking use this line of code,

```
<a href="#" onclick = "alert('fine')">test</a>
```

or this one,

```
<button onclick="alert('fine')">Click me</button>
```

Comment: 'fine' is the string that you want to display.

Comment: No it is not any part of sumome but the basic of html and javascript. So it should work any where. Unless your browser does not support javascript or it is turned off.

Comment: Please tell me your web browser name.

Comment: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/12654?hl=en
use this link and enable javascript.

Comment: no no it is not java. It is javascript. java and javascript are not the same they are not even related.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick
I think this demo will clear your doubt.